# Insert Google Maps HTML in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, google-maps

I want to insert a Google Map into Wordpress without paying for a plugin. I just want to adjust the style, add a few markers and add a description to the makers. Therefore I simple used the example code from Google Maps and adjusted the style. So far so good.

The question is now, how can I insert my code? It is more or less like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

If I can't add the code directly do you know any free plugin which would allow me to achieve my mentioned points (custom style, multiple markers, markers description)?

Regards,

x0100

edit:
I found a plugin which allowed me to to it for free "Google Maps Easy" (https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-maps-easy/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, which wordpress version you are using but all wordpress versions supports custom html embedding on page.

**Here's how you can do:** (WordPress 5.1.1)

1. Go to **Pages**
2. **Add**/**Edit** Page
3. Click on **Plus** Icon (step 1 in below screenshot)
4. Search for **Custom HTML** (step 2 in below screenshot)

[image]
5. **Paste** map html in page (sample available below)

[image]

**Keep in mind,** adding custom css and javascript; directly in page is not recommended!

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. This is exactly what I tried. When I afterwards load my WordPress page it shows no map and no error. Is it working for you?

I use WordPress 5.2.1.

When you say it is not recommended, which other option do I have?

Comment: Did you replace `YOUR_API_KEY` with actual API keys? Embedding javascript in page is not recommended, it should be enqueued in `functions.php` file; but that's complex for non-tech guys!